# ERROR en Api en node.js con mongodb y mongoose ( findByIdAndUpdate )

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una función dentro del controlador de usuarios (usuarios con jwt) para actualizar el usuario.

No veo error en el código ni en la consola. Al enviar la petición por posmatman me sale un error.

Este es el código del controlador.

```js
//edicion de usuarios
function updateUser(req, res){
  //recoger el id del usuario en la url
  var userId = req.params.id;
  
  var update = req.body;

  //borrar propiedad password del update
  delete update.password;

  //comprovamos que el token de la petición y el usario que se quiere modificar son el mismo
  if(userId != req.user.sub){
    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'You do not have permission to edit this user'});
  }

  //buscamos y actualizamos el usuario
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, update, {new: true}, (err, userUpdate) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Request error. Try again later'});

    if(!userUpdate) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Could not update user'});

    return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});
  });

}
```

y aquí os dejo el error que me sale a la consola al enviar la petición desde postman(con respuesta de erro)

```js
(node:16376) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: userUpdated is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te arroja el error de que `userUpdated` no está definido. Si te das cuenta tienes definido:

`(err, userUpdate)`

Y estás devolviendo:

```
return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated});
```

Lo correcto sería:

```
return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdate});
```

Comment: Si ahora si funciona pero sigue dando el error o warning este: (node:9440) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-

Comment: Eso es porque dentro de tu controlador estás llamando a métodos que están obsoletos si no estableces el parámetro `useFindAndModify` a `false`. Para solucionarlo copia este código antes de las llamadas a los métodos:  `mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);`